# At compile time generate type level Nats for constraint checking

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to have the value of an integer value represented at the type level at compile time such that I can check it against some constraints.

I would like users of the DSL to not have to write something like:

```
five = inc $ inc $ inc $ inc $ inc $ zero
```

Hence what I've been trying to create is a function which elevates that value to the type level.

ie

```
fromInt :: Int -> repr n
fromInt n = __
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
data Z
data S a

data IntNat a = IN Int

zero = (IN 0 :: IntNat Z)

inc :: IntNat a -> IntNat (S a)
inc (IN i) = (IN (i + 1))

fromInt :: Int -> IntNat a 
fromInt 0 = (IN 0 :: IntNat Z)
fromInt n = inc (fromInt (n - 1))
```

This however fails since I don't have a general enough representation of the IntNat, `IntNat Z ~/~ IntNat S Z`.

Is this approach generally flawed, or is it a case of needing to enclose `S Z` in a type family / type class?

The other classic example of this would be to generate a vector of a specific length when using type level length annotated vectors. That function should address the same problem that I am having.

Comment: This is not possible in Haskell, because it requires dependent types. There is no type signature for `fromInt` that will work.

Comment: Does Haskell not have dependent types? https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell

Comment: No, not of the kind you require. If you read the article you linked, you will notice that it does not allow the type signature you require.

Comment: You should add some more context why you want that. Broadly speaking, there are two very different ways you could approach this: with type families (as type-level functions) or with Template Haskell (to generate code for type expressions).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I take it with Template Haskell `fromInt` would generate the `inc $ inc $ ...` expression? What would the type family approach be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Haskell does not have dependent types, there’s no way to lift value-level `Int` to a type-level natural.  Depending on your use case, you have several approximating options.

#### Use continuation passing style

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

fromInt :: Int -> (forall a. IntNat a -> r) -> r
fromInt 0 f = f zero
fromInt n f = fromInt (n - 1) (f . inc)
```

#### Use an existential type

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data AnyIntNat = forall n. AnyIntNat (IntNat n)

fromInt :: Int -> AnyIntNat
fromInt 0 = AnyIntNat zero
fromInt n =
  case fromInt (n - 1) of
    AnyIntNat m -> AnyIntNat (inc m)
```

#### Take advantage of the existing type-level literals

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts,
  TypeApplications, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances
  #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

class GetIntNat n where
  getIntNat :: IntNat n

instance GetIntNat Z where
  getIntNat = zero

instance GetIntNat n => GetIntNat (S n) where
  getIntNat = inc getIntNat

type family Peano n where
  Peano 0 = Z
  Peano n = S (Peano (n - 1))

-- usage: fromNat @5
fromNat :: GetIntNat (Peano n) => IntNat (Peano n)
fromNat = getIntNat
```

Comment: I take it the core issue is that for any given function the result type has to be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like users of the DSL to not have to write something like:
>
> ```
> five = inc $ inc $ inc $ inc $ inc $ zero
> ```

This is the sort of thing you could easily write a quasiquoter for, but in this case you can use GHC's support for type-level Nat literals, converting to your representation using type families (which are type-level functions).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances  #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data Z
data S a

type family FromNat (n :: Nat) where
  FromNat 0 = Z
  FromNat n = S (FromNat (n - 1))

fromNat :: Proxy n -> Proxy (FromNat n)
fromNat _ = Proxy
```

You also get some things like type-level addition etc

```
*Main GHC.TypeLits Data.Proxy> :t fromNat (Proxy :: Proxy 5)
fromNat (Proxy :: Proxy 5) :: Proxy (S (S (S (S (S Z)))))
*Main GHC.TypeLits Data.Proxy> :t fromNat (Proxy :: Proxy (3 + 2))
fromNat (Proxy :: Proxy (3 + 2)) :: Proxy (S (S (S (S (S Z)))))
```

**EDIT**: Anders in first with an answer, but leaving this as an alternative implementation